# What if I want to choose another answer as correct one?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

After reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-10-minutes-after-asking-the-question) it is obvious that we should give the community a chance.

But if we are talking about full chances, maybe time versus quality. Should not answers be ranked like:

- First correct answer (fastest)
- Second correct answer (better quality and resolution)?

Answer (score 7):

Questions on SO are such that there is one correct answer.  If you decide over time that a different answer is better, choose that different answer - that happened to one of my old answers yesterday, when it was proven slightly inferior by the OP learning further information months later.

What value is there in saying an answer was almost-as-good if one was clearly more useful to you (the OP)?  If both are pretty good, the votes will show - both answers will get plenty of votes and a future reader will understand.

Comment: you know people are always looking for that green mark ! how many times have you seen comments stating this should have been correct answer just because teh topic is old and the OP doesnt care anymore.

Comment: @ProllyGeek, that's exactly why we have upvotes. The massively upvoted answers will rise to the top, so that it doesn't matter what the OP picked in the end. The only real difference is that additional `+15` rep that the OP can dole out.

Comment: that 15+ rep makes difference dont you think so ?

Comment: Rep is not the point of SO.

Comment: @zzzzBov you still right though many upvotes are the matter not the correct answer.